# WPF Binding: How do I reference element outside a user control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

My main window has following portion of XAML

```
<StackPanel>
 <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" />
 <my:UserControl1 />
</StackPanel>
```

my:UserControl1 goes like this

```
<TextBox x:Name="userControlTextBox" />
```

I would like to bind the above textbox's Text property to Text property of the textbox outside. 
I have tried

```
<TextBox x:Name="userControlTextBox" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=textbox1.Text}" />
```

Comment: If userControlTextBox is specific to this window, why don't you implement it as part of the window instead of in a UserControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind like you shown in the question. There are two ways to achieve that:

***First***, bind Text of textBox1 to some property in ViewModel. And bind Text of userControlTextBox to same bound property.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

and in UserControl

```
<TextBox x:Name="userControlTextBox" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

Make sure your property is notifiable *(INPC should be implemented by containing class)* so that any changes in it gets propagated to GUI.

---

***Second*** would be to create custom DP on your userControl of type string. Bind that DP with Text value of textbox1. And bind Text of userControlTextBox to that DP.

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" />
  <my:UserControl1 TextValue="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox1}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Here, **`TextValue`** is custom DP declared in your userControl.

```
public string CustomValue
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(CustomValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CustomValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CustomValue", typeof(string),
                                 typeof(UserControl1));
```

Now, bind textBox in UserControl like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="userControlTextBox"
         Text="{Binding TextValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                         AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```